# Emplicitly tag a row in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to tag a single row in a treeview column when it is selected.

```
BadgesView.tag_configure("BadgeOfTheWeek", background="yellow")
```

Before or after this row is tagged I want the other rows to have all their tags removed by the program.

```
for row in Treeview:
    remove tag from row.
```

I am not sure if this is possible, as I  am having a hard time identifying which row is the selected row, and from that which row to tag.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @stovfl I want the program to remove all tags associated with each row. Sorry for lack of clarity.

Comment: Dahm, that's a shame :(

Comment: I think saying they are readonly is false. You can change the tags at any time, including changing them to an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... the other `rows` to have all their `tags` removed

---

> [Tkinter 8.5 reference - 45. ttk.Treeview](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html)
>    First, some definitions:
>   `item`
>   One of the entities being displayed in the widget. For a file browser, an item might be either a directory or a file.
>   Each item is associated with a textual label, and may also be associated with an image.
>   `iid`
>   Every item in the tree has a unique identifier string called the iid. You can supply the iid values yourself, or you can let ttk generate them.

---

> `Treeview` `items` before:
>
> ```
> item:{'text': 'Text_1', 'values': '', 'tags': ['ALL'], 'image': '', 'open': 0}
> item:{'text': 'Text_2', 'values': '', 'tags': ['BadgeOfTheWeek', 'ALL'], 'image': '', 'open': 0}
> item:{'text': 'Text_3', 'values': '', 'tags': ['ALL'], 'image': '', 'open': 0}
> ```

- Loop the `Treeview` to get the `iid` of a item

  ```
  for iid in self.tree.get_children():
  ```
- Condition: `'BadgeOfTheWeek'` is **`not in`** current `item(iid)` `tags`.

  ```
      if not 'BadgeOfTheWeek' in self.tree.item(iid)['tags']:
  ```
- To **remove** all `tags` from this `item(iid)`, set `tags=` to a empty `list` or `set`

  ```
          self.tree.item(iid, tags=[])
  ```

> `Treeview` `items` after:
>
> ```
> item:{'text': 'Text_1', 'values': '', 'tags': '', 'image': '', 'open': 0}
> item:{'text': 'Text_2', 'values': '', 'tags': ['BadgeOfTheWeek', 'ALL'], 'image': '', 'open': 0}
> item:{'text': 'Text_3', 'values': '', 'tags': '', 'image': '', 'open': 0}
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - TkVersion: 8.6***